# Why is Zend_Form's best use for "RAD and prototyping"?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Can someone explain why it's best use is for prototyping?  Should it not be used in a production app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend_Form can be and I'm sure is used in production on many sites.
The reason you likely hear that Zend_Form is best used in prototyping is because with the way the current decorator's are used it can be very difficult to get exactly the look or code many people want.
Also support for multipage forms and very complex forms can be limited or require alot of work to get right.
The trick to making Zend_Form easier is to learn the *viewScript* decorator, it's not perfect but it does help.